# How to add a custom page in the Admin Area of X-Cart 4.X?

Tags: x-cart

I want to build a custom Settings page on the back-end of X-Cart. I've been scanning the files and so far I was only able to learn how to add my link to the admin menu page and I was also able to build the page and assign contents using smarty. The only thing that is missing now in my custom page is the X-Cart's admin header and footer sections, all I see is the text outputted using smarty with plain white background only.

Here is what I did to create the admin menu link and the page:

1) I created a sample_settings.php on the folder: **root/admin/** with the following contents:

```
<?php  
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
require $xcart_dir.'/include/security.php';

$smarty->assign('text', 'test text');

$smarty->assign('main', 'sample_settings');

func_display('admin/main/sample_settings.tpl', $smarty);
```

2) Then I created the sample_settings.tpl on the folder: **root/skin/customs_skin/admin/main/** with the following contents:

```
{$text}
```

3) Then I assigned my new file in the **root/skin/customs_skin/singe/home.tpl** just before the else:

```
{elseif $main eq "sample_settings"}
{include file="admin/main/sample_settings.tpl"}
```

4) Then to add the menu item to the "Content" tab in the X-Cart admin menu, I added the following code to the file: **root/skin/customs_skin/singe/menu_box.tpl**

```
<a href="{$catalogs.admin}/sample_settings.php">Sample Settings</a>
```

So what did I miss?

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want x-cart header and footer, a classic admin page, than you should include:

```
func_display('admin/home.tpl',$smarty);
```

and **NOT**

```
func_display('admin/main/sample_settings.tpl', $smarty);
```

Everything else looks quite correct.